# Receiving an error of when trying to add text to a label in a collection view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to input the arrayOfValues[indexPath.item] as the text for my textLabel in the collection view, but receive an error when I run the program saying 'Fatal error: Index Out of Range'

How would I fix this so that the collectionView cells are populated with information from the arrayOfValues?

Here is the code.

```
import UIKit

class NetworkViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var firstCollectionView: UICollectionView!
@IBOutlet weak var secondCollectionView: UICollectionView!

let arrayOfOrganizations = ["My Network", "Find Connections", "ss"]
let arrayOfValues = [""]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if (collectionView == secondCollectionView) {
        return arrayOfOrganizations.count
    }
    return arrayOfValues.count
 }

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let firstCell = firstCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstCollectionViewCell
    firstCell.textLabel.text = arrayOfValues[indexPath.item] //error on this line
    if (collectionView == secondCollectionView) {
        let secondCell = secondCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCollectionViewCell
        secondCell.backgroundColor = .black
        return secondCell
    }
    return firstCell
 }

}

class FirstCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!

}

class SecondCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

}
```

Comment: If you really need two collectionviews simultaneously, I would suggest you implement their delegates and data sources as two separate classes, so none of those mixups can happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you had was the the first two lines of your cellForItemAt function were getting executed no matter the collectionView. So, essentially, you need to make sure the block of code corresponding to the firstCollectionView gets executed only when collectionView == firstCollectionView, and same goes for the secondCollectionView. In short, you just need to change your function to this instead:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if (collectionView == secondCollectionView) {
        let secondCell = secondCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "secondCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondCollectionViewCell
        secondCell.backgroundColor = .black
        return secondCell
    } else {
         let firstCell = firstCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "firstCell", for: indexPath) as! FirstCollectionViewCell
         firstCell.textLabel.text = arrayOfValues[indexPath.item] //error on this line
         return firstCell
    }
 }
```